# how to extract rownumber from spplot map

Tags: r, geospatial, spatial

I have a `SpatialPointsDataFrame` with `@data` like this:

[image]

Using `spplot(object, "variable")` I draw map with coloured points (high-low values)
I want to know the row number of some points on my map. 
Something like this:

click on the points which interest me -> print rownumber

I tried `select.spatial(object, digitize = FALSE)` but, map doesn't show colour points (high-low values) but all of my points are black.

Comment: please provide a reproducible example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: spplot(object, "variable", identify=TRUE) it was what i was looking for